# Connecting mouse to phone

Tags: usb, usb-otg, mouse

I'm trying to connect my mouse to my phone but I broke my otg cable. So I split a slimport wire that fits my phone and matches the mouse wire and wired it together but when I plug it into my phone the mouse doesn't turn on or work at all. I checked both of them before spliting them and they both work. Instead of buying a new otg cable I want to figure out how else I can make it work by rewiring it somehow. Can anyone help on how to fix it or different ideas? I also reconnected the usb port.

Comment: This article has a similar question. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30752/does-android-usb-host-mode-depend-on-an-otg-cable?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go#OTG_micro_plugs), an OTG cable has to have an extra connection (ID) with a resistor or connection to ground.

Its value depends on how you want the devices to be powered / interact:

> **Short to GND** - Becomes OTG A device
>
> **124 kΩ -** A charger and either no device or an A-device that is not asserting 
>   VBUS (not providing power) are attached. The OTG device is allowed to
>   charge and initiate SRP but not connect.
>
> **68 kΩ** - A charger and an A-device that is asserting VBUS (is providing power)
>   are attached. The OTG device is allowed to charge and connect but not
>   initiate SRP.
>
> **36.5 kΩ** - A charger and a B-device are attached. The OTG device is allowed to
>   charge and enter host mode.

So I'm afraid that using a random micro USB cable will not work. You need to find one that has an internal connection to the extra pin(ID) and short it to GND:

[image]

Comment: ...and for the usual purpose its going to be easier to just buy another commodity adapter cable than find something with the fifth wire to modify.  Though adafruit (and presumably others) do have a do-it-yourself micro connector which appears to have five connections.

Comment: @ChrisStratton -- I've been through a similar situation earlier this year and I needed to add a resistor. So it made sense to buy a micro connector instead of an adapter with the short. I was hoping this answer could help people in various scenarios.